# Why are we telling people to upvote answers solely on the basis of the question being helpful?

Tags: discussion, support, design

I was just using Google and wandered onto SO and happened to see this pop-up:

> Welcome back! If you found this question useful,
>   don't forget to vote both the question **and the answers** up.

This doesn't make sense to me. A question being helpful to me means it was either relevant to my Google search or it matched my problem. However, I fail to see how the question being worthy of upvote automatically means I should upvote the answers. What if I don't find anything helpful in the answers? What if it were just the question itself being useful and nothing else? I don't see why I should blindly upvote an answer without reading it based on the content of the question. Could someone explain this pop-up?

Comment: My guess: The assumption when it was written was that if someone found the question useful it was at least partly because it had at least one helpful answer. Not really how we actually define the usefulness of questions though. It should say something like, "and any useful answers up".

Comment: I agree it could be worded better, but I've never had any illusions that I had to upvote everything anyone posted.

Comment: @SandPiper Well yeah, but I'm familiar with the culture of SE. Outsiders might have no clue that that is bad practice and assume it is normal to do so. We cannot assume anything about the audience of that banner. I believe it even appeared once when I was logged out.

Comment: But also to be fair, if you're brand spanking new to SO you can't vote anyway.

Comment: @SandPiper I wonder if brand spanking new users even get this banner. It does say welcome *back* instead of just welcome. Maybe you have to have a certain level of rep or you just have to have an account and have not been on the site for a while.

Comment: @BSMP nope. I get it whenever visiting through an external link. Scratch that. Visiting through an external link for the first time in my browsing session.

Comment: In my experience most high traffic questions have more upvotes on the top answer than on the question itself. So I would interpret this popup as encouraging visitors to _also_ upvote the question. The first "question" would be referring to the page as a whole, i.e. question + answers.

Comment: Maybe they should just reword it to: `Welcome back! If you found this question useful, don't forget to vote both the question and any useful answers up.`

Comment: @MattCoubrough i like that better. Once again, it is technically semantics but I don't want new people to get confused.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Just going to chime in here, I think referring to the entire post as a "question" seems a bit vague, just saying... (as in "If you found this *question* helpful")

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/445088#445088

Comment: IMO: cut it out with the nag instructions (AKA "friendly reminder") entirely, no matter what is done to this really poorly executed text it will always remain a fraction of the truth. People need to end up in the tour and the help center which are far better tools to make people aware of what they can do and what they should (and should not) do.

Comment: @Gimby sounds good